# “How to fix ‘handlePress’ error in react-native”

Tags: react-native

Below is my login class code :

```
export default class Login extends Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        loggedIn: true,
    }

    handlePress = () => {
        this.props.onHomeviewPress(this.state.data);
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text style={{ color: "blue", fontSize: 28, marginLeft: 10 }}> Login</Text>
            <TextInput style={styles.input}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                placeholder="Email"
                placeholderTextColor="blue"
                autoCapitalize="none"
            />

            <TextInput style={styles.input}
                underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
                placeholder="Password"
                placeholderTextColor="blue"
                autoCapitalize="none"
            />

            <Button
                onPress={() => this.handlePress.bind(this)}
                title="Login"
            />
        </View>
    );
  }
}
```

HAVING PROBLEM IN HANDLEPRESS FUNCTION IS NOT WORKING GIVING ERROR

> undefined is not an object('_this2.handlepress.bind')

Please Help me solve this. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `handlePress` function is defined in your constructor.

Move it outside and it will work

Also, you don't need to bind the function. Just `onPress={this.handlePress}` will work.

Comment: Thanks Jaon ! It's Works